# Nodejs: write to stdin of bash process crashes with EPIPE

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, stdin

My node process gets some PDF file via HTTP Request, then uses the request's `onData` event to pass the incoming data on to a properly configured `lpr`, spawned via `child_process.exec`. I write to stdin using `process.stdin.write(...)`, followed by `process.stdin.end()` when done. This allows me to print those files immediately.

Now I have a situation where I don't want the data to be piped to `lpr`, but to some bash script. The script uses `cat` to process its `stdin`.

`myscript.sh < somefile.pdf` works as expected, as does `cat somefile.pdf | myscript.sh`.

However, when I spawn `/path/to/script.sh` from node (by simply replacing `lpr` with the script path in the source), the process exits with

`events.js:183
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:868:14)`

Subsequently, the whole node process crashes, the error sneaking around all `try...catch` blocks. Logging at the beginning of the bash script shows, it does not even get started.

When I target anything that's not a shell script but some compiled executable, like `cat`, `echo`,... everything works just fine.
Adding [epipebomb module](https://github.com/mhart/epipebomb) would not change anything.

I also tried piping to `process.exec("bash", ["-c cat | myscript.sh"])`, with the same errors.

An example bash script, just to test for execution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
date > logfile.txt
cat > /dev/null
```

EDIT:
I think I maybe need to signal to keep the stdin stream open somehow.
The process-spawning part of the script, leaving promisification and output processing away:

```
const process = require("child_process")    

// inputObservable being an rxjs Observable
execstuff(inputObervable) {
  const task = process.spawn("/path/to/script.sh");
  inputObservable.subscribe(
    chunk => task.stdin.write(chunk),
    error => console.error(error),
    finished => task.stdin.end()
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your script, I have an intuition that you are not using properly streams...

Comment: I added some code @AlexandruOlaru

Comment: Was there any acceptable solution to this? @waechtertroll

Answer (score 1):

There is an example at [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) how you can write the following lines `ps ax | grep ssh` as node.js script, maybe it will be helpful for you:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ps = spawn('ps', ['ax']);
const grep = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  grep.stdin.write(data);
});

ps.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`ps stderr: ${data}`);
});
```

> The first impression is that you are doing the same stuff, the problem may be in the chunk data, maybe one of the chunks is null, and it is closing the stream, and you want to close it by running task.stdin.end().

The other thing you can try is to run the node.js script with the `NODE_DEBUG=stream node script.js`
Will log the node.js internals how the stream, behaves, also may be helpful for you.

Comment: I know that manual and I think it does basically the same thing. I could fix the crashing - during debug I had inserted some logging into the shell script, which closed stdin, so Node was right when it reported a closed stream.

Comment: Still, the data does not seem to arrive in the script file. The data is raw Buffers, which get simply passed over, no premature `null`s are in it.
I'll try the stream debug env variable now.